# android studio do a socket connection when screen is unlock?(java)

Tags: java, android-studio, background-process

I want that each time that the user unlock his phone my app automatically do a socket connection in background to see if the user had receive a message, and if yes show a notification.

the code to do a socket connection and do a notification works in the MainActivity class but I could find out to make that the android device execute the code in the UserPresentBroadcastReceiver class automatically even if the app has not been open.

android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.notification">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Notification">
        <receiver android:name=".UserPresentBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <!--For HTC devices-->
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="UserPresentBroadcastReceiver" >
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"  />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the UserPresentBroadcastReceiver class

```
package com.example.notification;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class UserPresentBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;

    private String message_sortant;
    private BufferedReader in_bufferedReader;
    private String message_entrant;
    private InputStreamReader in_streamReader;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

        /*Sent when the user is present after
         * device wakes up (e.g when the keyguard is gone)
         * */

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
            while(true) {
                try {

                    //Log.d("Connexion","Demande de connexion");
                    Socket client = new Socket("192.168.1.13", 1580);// connect to the server

                    //////  ENVOIE D'UN MESSAGE SORTANT ///////
                    Log.d("Connexion", "Envoie de A");
                    printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                    printwriter.write("<meet>/notification/"); // write the message to output stream

                    printwriter.flush();


                    in_bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                    message_entrant = in_bufferedReader.readLine();
                    client.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {


                }
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID",
                            "YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME",
                            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                    channel.setDescription("YOUR_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION");
                    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                }
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(arg0.getApplicationContext(), "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // notification icon
                        .setContentTitle("hello") // title for notification
                        .setContentText(String.valueOf(message_entrant))// message for notification
                        .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click
                intent = new Intent(arg0.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
                mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }
        /*Device is shutting down. This is broadcast when the device
         * is being shut down (completely turned off, not sleeping)
         * */
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN)) {

        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for helping.
I notice that they change something with android Oreo but I couldn't find out how to fix it.